# How to query and get only consecutive rows with the same column(s) value(s)

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have this `activities` table generated by the `public_activity` `gem`. Which has this two fields `key` `owner_id` part from others.

I'm trying to query the activities in **chunks** base on the `owner_id` and the `key` columns.
So if we have this data:

```
|  id  |  owner_id  |  key             |
| ---- | ---------- |  --------------  |
|  1   |  1         |  product.create  |
|  2   |  1         |  product.create  |
|  3   |  1         |  product.update  |
|  4   |  2         |  product.update  |
|  5   |  2         |  product.destroy |
|  6   |  2         |  product.destroy |
|  7   |  2         |  product.destroy |
|  8   |  1         |  product.create  |
|  9   |  1         |  product.create  |
```

The **chunks** would the matching rows.
Represented here by ids:

```
[1,2]
[3]
[4]
[5,6,7]
[8,9]
```

**Chunks** will be loaded one at a time via ajax, so the query will be preceded with a condition `where(id > the_last_activity_fetched_id)`

Any thoughts on how to build the necessary query are really welcome.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this using [array_agg](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-aggregate.html):

```
select key,owner_id , array_agg(id) chunks from 
    (select key,owner_id,id from my_table order by id) A
group by  key,owner_id
order by chunks
```

Here is an example: [SQLFIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/1b534/5)

Answer (score 2):

Using [array_agg()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-aggregate.html)

```
select owner_id,key, array_agg(id) chunks 
from t
group by  1,2
order by 3
```

[`Demo`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d0271/4)

or

[string_agg()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-aggregate.html)

```
select owner_id,key,string_agg(id::text,',') chunks 
from t 
group by 1,2
order by 3
```

[`Demo`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d0271/2)

---

As per OP's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33969938/how-to-query-and-get-only-consecutive-rows-with-the-same-columns-values/33970105?noredirect=1#comment55697065_33970105)

```
select owner_id,key
      , array_agg(id) chunks 
from t 
group by 1,2 order by 3 desc limit 1
```

Comment: Here I'm getting all the chunks but what I need is the last one.

Comment: why?? and what is the condition ?

Comment: @Marwen Try this `select owner_id,key, array_agg(id) chunks 
from t
group by  1,2
order by 3 desc limit 1`

Comment: As I said in the question, chunks will be loaded one at a time. They likely will be preceded by a condition on the id: `where(id > 20)`

Comment: @Marwen  check 3rd comment?? still couldn't get the correct answer then provide more clarification and the query that you are using

Comment: Yeah okay this is better, thank! I will try to integrate this with `ruby on rails` and see where it goes

Comment: There a little problem with the solution you gave. Using `array_agg` or `string_agg` I'am getting all the rows even if they are not consecutive. Please take a look again at the example, I modified it so you can see what I am talking about.